# Different size screens for gaming - android

Tags: android, game-development

I have asked this before however I am still having issues with this problem!

Basically, I am hardcoding pixel values when using a canvas to draw images for a game.

How would I go about the process of making this game suitable for any screen size as obviously the pixel values for one screen wont run properly on a different screen!

Thanks in advance

Ben

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061258/multiple-screen-resolutions-aspect-ratios-games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need pixel values? Use dp not px values!!

```
final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int px = (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f);
```

> dp Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the
>   physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi
>   (dots per inch) screen, so 160dp is always one inch regardless of the
>   screen density. The ratio of dp-to-pixel will change with the screen
>   density, but not necessarily in direct proportion. You should use
>   these units when specifying view dimensions in your layout, so the UI
>   properly scales to render at the same actual size on different
>   screens. (The compiler accepts both "dip" and "dp", though "dp" is
>   more consistent with "sp".)

Comment: how do i do that for drawing to a canvas?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use the following in order to get the screen dimensions:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Then decide what to do as you see fit - stretch your original resolution to fit, draw directly to the larger res, etc.

If your canvas is only part of the screen, keep track of its relative position to the top left and scale the positions/sizes accordingly.