# setting orientation and aspect ratio in android multiple screen support

Tags: android

I found that there are 4 aspects to change the android application for multiple screen support.

1.screen size
2. screen density
3.orientation(portrait/landscape)
4.aspect ratio(long/not long)

I have clear idea about screen size,density and orientation. But I don't know how to identify aspect ratio. Is it necessary to explicitly create folder for orientation and aspect ratio?. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question

[Multiple screen resolutions/aspect ratios (games)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061258/multiple-screen-resolutions-aspect-ratios-games)

And also from doc read this thing

> The orientation of the screen from the user's point of view. This is
>   **either landscape or portrait**, **meaning that the screen's aspect ratio
>   is either wide or tall**, respectively.
>
> Be aware that not only do
>   different devices operate in different orientations by default, but
>   the orientation can change at runtime when the user rotates the
>   device.

**Resources for screens in the landscape orientation (wide aspect ratio).**

**Resources for screens in the portrait orientation (tall aspect ratio).**

Comment: thanks for your answer. And also I have one more doubt. If I consider combination of these 4 aspects, there will be 64 layout folders will be created in res folder. Is it necessary?

Comment: @AntonyPaulRaj you just need to at max 8 Res Folder 4 for Portrait and 4 for Landscape
you can Map the Layouts with DIPS difference of all 4 layout 
for LDPI  
f
Pixel Mapping is 
0.75:1
for MDPI 
1:1
for HDPI 
1.5:1
and for XHDPI 

2:1